# Change AbsoluteSizeSpan text size after creation

Tags: android, spannablestring

I've created a Span and set it's text size using this code :

```
sb.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(myFontSize), 0, title.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Now I want to let user change span text size, I tried :

```
SpannedString sb=(SpannedString)getText();
            AbsoluteSizeSpan[] list = sb.getSpans(0, getText().length(), AbsoluteSizeSpan.class);
            for (AbsoluteSizeSpan asp:list)
            {
// how I changed asp text size?
            }
```

Comment: how?  its simple: you can't

Answer (score 0):

`AbsoluteSizeSpan` is a fairly simple class, whose complete source code you can get [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/style/AbsoluteSizeSpan.java).

You can copy this class into your own project and improve it, such as by adding a `setSize` method.